# Redirection to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, server, httpd.conf

Here is the tree of my project :

```
/project1
    /public
         page1.php
         page2.php
/project2
      ...
```

I would like to access my pages with
**/project1/page1.php** and not **/project1/public/page1.php**

But I also want to not have access to pages by going to **/project1/public/***

I know that I have to manage this with a .htaccess file or httpd.conf file but after trying all the solutions available on several sites, I still can not get what I want.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english level.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution but I don't know if it's proper :

`<VirtualHost *:8888>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "dev"
        Alias /project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/public
        <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/public>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`